# How to get the interface used to join a multicast group programmatically?

Tags: c, networking, routes, ipv6, multicast

Is there a way to find which interface has been used to join an IPv6 multicast group, if the index used was 0 meaning that we leave to the kernel to choose which interface is suitable. 
Can we get that information afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the IPV6_MULTICAST_IF socket option change after the join is complete? If not you'll have to look at the interface table and see which is the default, on windows this would be done with GetAdaptersAddresses, no idea for *nix.

Comment: no this socket option remains the same, I just want to know which interface has been chosen by the kernel